# Recursive Sum not evaluating correctly

Tags: summation, recursion

I'm trying to evaluate the following sums that nest into eachother:

$$
m_k=\frac{k}{k-1} \left(e^{\gamma}+ \sum_{i=1}^{k-2} {k-1\choose i} \frac{m_i}{i}   \right)
\\
m_1=e^\gamma
$$
and
$$
\kappa_n = m_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose i}m_i\kappa_{n-i}
\\
\kappa_1 = m_1 
$$

With the following code:

```
moment[1] = E^(EulerGamma);
moment[k_] := 
 k/(k - 1) (E^(EulerGamma) + 
    Sum[Binomial[(k - 1), i]*moment[i]/i, {i, 1, k - 2}])
```

and

```
cum[1] = moment[1];
cum[n_] := 
 moment[n] - 
  Sum[moment[i]*cum[n - i]*Binomial[n - 1, i], {i, 1, n - 1}]
```

But it's calculating wrong on $\kappa_4$. Am I missing something?

The results I'm trying to replicate come from a paper that offer the first 4 values of $\kappa$ to be:

$$
1.781072 \quad 0.3899259 \quad 0.2814155 \quad  0.2399205
$$
And my results are:
$$
1.78107 \quad 0.389926 \quad 0.281416 \quad -3.32222$$

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what exactly is wrong: What answer do you expect and why? Also, there is some chaos with letters, $k_{n-i}$ should perhaps be $\kappa_{n-i}$ and $k_4$ should perhaps be $\kappa_4$...

Comment: Just made the edits. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Have you considered that the paper could be wrong? Can you provide a link (ideally open access)?

Comment: Maybe it works out fine but is `moment[2]` equal to $2 e^{\gamma }$ ?  I ask because the `Sum` goes from $i=1$ to $i=k-2$ which is $i=1$ to $i=0$.

Comment: Yes @JimB is probably right. moment[2] is not defined correctly!!! Please check out once again the recurrent definition of moments.

Comment: How to choose proper value of "n"???

Comment: @michalkvasnicka  it should be $\kappa_n = ...$. Corrected.

Comment: @JimB Yes you're correct that ``moment[2]`` is $2e^\gamma$. It does work out fine in the code.

Comment: @user293787 I can't provide a link to the paper but I'll post the relevant bit here. I'm hesitant to assume an error in the paper because the negative values of $\kappa$ are significant. They are cumulants to a distribution and I think it would be major error. I've contacted the author to check.

Comment: There is still the problem with the first recurrent formula for moments! For k=1,2 is not mathematically correct!!! Sum limits are not define well. Is this formula valid only for k>2?